# Creation date in Windows CMD

Tags: batch-file, filenames

Using Windows batch, this function returns creation dates of a file:

```
:creationDate
set "CompareFile=%~1"
echo !CompareFile!
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4,5* delims= " %%a in ('dir  /a:-d /o:d /t:c') do (
    if "%%~c" NEQ "bytes" (
        if "%%~d"=="!CompareFile!" ( set "%~2=%%~a %%~b" )
    )
)
goto:eof
```

---

### Example usage:

```
call :creationDate "!MyFile!" MyFileCreationDate
echo !MyFile! was made on !MyFileCreationDate!
```

---

### The Variables in the function:

```
%%~a = Creation Date
%%~b = Creation Time
%%~d = Filename (error when there is spaces!)

%%~1 = Filename to get the creation date for
%%~2 = Variable to store creation date in
```

---

But it does not work on filenames with spaces or special characters.  In that case %%~d maybe will contain just the first few letters of the filename, or nothing, resulting in no value being returned to argument 2

---

The goal is to get it to match to a filename w/ spaces I've passed to a subroutine as argument 1 and return argument 2 as the creation date of argument 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=."

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 CALL :creationdate "%sourcedir%\%%a" c crdatetime
 CALL :creationdate "%sourcedir%\%%a" w wrdatetime
 CALL :creationdate "%sourcedir%\%%a" a acdatetime
 ECHO !crdatetime! !wrdatetime! !acdatetime! %%a

)

GOTO :EOF

:creationDate
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (
 'dir  /a:-d /o:d /t:%2 "%~1"') do set "%~3=%%~a %%~b"&goto:eof
goto:eof
```

Although I'd change the name of the routine.

Comment: Thank you!  This version has all the extra goodness I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

- Why don't you include the file name in the dir command?
- To exclude other lines of the dir you could pipe to a findstr.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2017-04\30\SO_43708547.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "MyFile=%~1"

call :creationDate "!MyFile!" MyFileCreationDate
echo !MyFile! was made on !MyFileCreationDate!

Goto :Eof

:creationDate
for /f "tokens=1-3* delims= " %%a in (
  'dir  /a:-d /o:d /t:c "%~1" ^| findstr /i "%~nx1$" '
) do set "%~2=%%~a %%~b"

goto:eof
```

Sample output (with my user settings date format):

```
> SO_43708547.cmd "test name.txt"
test name.txt was made on 2017-04-30 18:49
```

**Edit** Changed test file to include a space.