# Listing files and folders and outputting it as .csv

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script to list all the folders, sub-folders and files inside a directory, and then output everything to a .csv-file. I have tried this using the `tree` command but I also need the "Creation date" and "Last modified" date to be included. The `tree` command doesn't seem to support that. Is there any other way to do it?

Example:

[image: example]

```
tree "C:\Windows" /A /F > "C:\Log.csv"
```

Comment: Here's three ideas for you, Powershell, [tag:powershell] and `powershell`...

Comment: You claim you want CSV, but then imply TREE is good except it doesn't include any dates. The TREE output is not remotely like CSV, so what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @dbenham It doesn't necessarily have to be in .csv format as it can be converted later on (if needed). With a little formatting and using the tree command I am currently producing an output like this: https://imgur.com/NyDmey2 . All that it needs is the "last modified date" after the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

Use a PowerShell one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime|Export-Csv C:\log.csv -NotypeInformation
```

if necessary wrapped in a batch:

```
powershell -NoP -C "Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime|Export-Csv C:\log.csv -NotypeInformation"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `Dir /S *.*`?

The `/S` stands for "go through the directory and all subdirectories".

Sorry. I missed the part where you needed the creation dates. Those ones can be achieved as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708547/creation-date-in-windows-cmd).